# material missing in render preview

Tags: modeling

This is just a plane for a backdrop. The ground has a water drop texture and the back wall is solid color. It looks right in the preview, but I wanted to render it to see how everything looks, and only the plane object is messing up. For some reason the water drops are only visible in a small section and halfway up the backdrop wall it turns black.

3d render preview
[image: preview]

render results
[image: render results]

Comment: Hello :). Difference between viewport/render is often caused by modifiers or displacement

Comment: I found out what was causing the issue. I had another version of a different backdrop design that I hid but didn't turn off from rendering.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to delete this question, but I just made a mistake by forgetting to not let a hidden layer not render.